# How to kill someone in Minecraft using the console

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In the server console I tried

```
kill <playername>
```

But I get

```
[INFO] You must specify which player you wish to perform this action on.
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: Did you try the complete name? exp. typing Dan instead of Dan_theman.

Comment: And... just checking, but you did put the actual player name instead of "<playername>? Have to ask.

Comment: yes full name as used to login to Minecraft

Comment: IIRC you need to specify the player's current ID on the server. Type list to get it.

Comment: /list just lists player names (minecraft logins)

Comment: Make sure you're dropping the angle brackets as well. ie, "kill Keaanu" instead of "kill <Keaanu>"

Comment: I'm so tempted to edit the question title to just "How to kill someone"

Comment: @Dycker +5000 for DanTheMan...X-Ray & Vav salute you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
/kill
```

Is not a OP command but a player command to commit suicide so it can only apply to the one who use it. ([Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/SMP_Server_commands))

But... if your server is running on Bukkit, you could install [Essentials](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/essentials/) plugin and the you'll be able to use the command

```
/kill <playername>
```

and a lot of other useful stuff that every server moderator should have. But if you are not on bukkit or any modded server then why don't you

```
/tp <playername> <yourname>
```

so the player will be teleported to you and then just kill him :D

Comment: I prefer drinking a fire resist potion and going for a swim in lava before tp'ing someone to me. It really ups the fun factor.

Comment: or just type /tphere <playername> insted of /tp <playername> <yourname> :D

Comment: /tphere is again an Essentials command, not present in vanilla Minecraft.

Comment: Or, if you're using CommandBook, there's `/shock -k` which kills the player immediately, or `/shock` (which prolongs the death, making it a tad more fun).

Answer (score 5):

One thing that you can do is simply do `/tp <playername> x y z` with a large negative `y` (and any `x` and `z`). They will quickly die of void damage even if they're already flying in Creative Mode. It has to be a *large* negative `y`, since void damage doesn't begin until `-64` and flying Creative Mode players could just hover safely and tunnel back up. For example:

```
/tp <playername> 0 -1000 0
```

The only drawback is that the player's items will disappear entirely if you do this. However, depending on the circumstances, it sometimes is still good enough.

Comment: A better way is to use `/tp <player> ~0 -1000 ~0` so that **the player will stay at the same chunk and reduce overhead in chunk loading**.

Answer (score 4):

**For Minecraft >=1.5:**

You can put the "instant damage" potion effect on the player using the `/effect` command:

```
/effect <Player> 7 30 200
```

This gives "instant damage" effect (id `7`) to `<player>` for `30` seconds<sup>1</sup> with amplifier of `200`<sup>2</sup>.

Since each level deals 3 hearts of damage, amplifier of `200` should deal **600 hearts** of damage which should be enough to kill the player most of the time.

Exceptions where this method don't work: when the player is in creative mode, or the player has a <s>really strong</s> level 5<sup>3 (**not 5 to the power 3**)</sup> <s>regeneration</s> resistance effect (e.g. via custom potions or `/effect` command, see below). It also doesn't work during a 3-second interval right after the player respawns from death (data obtained via experimenting).

---

Note that when the player has a level 5 resistance effect, **the player is immune to most (if not all) damages**. That means **even falling into the void and/or executing `/kill`**.

You can try the following commands (in client or SSP):

```
/effect <Player> 11 1000000 5
/kill
/tp <Player> ~0 -1000 ~0
```

After executing these commands you should still be alive but not dead.

Though, you can still "attempt" to remove the "resistance" effect by the following command before attempting to kill the player:

```
/effect <Player> 11 0
```

---

Sources: Minecraft Wiki - [Commands](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands) and [Status effect](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Status_effect)

<sup>Notes:</sup>

1. The duration time doesn't really matter, I choose 30 seconds simply because it is the default value.
2. Values above 252 doesn't work (possible bug?). For values above 248 the behaviour is a bit strange - there is a short delay.
3. From the Minecraft Wiki...?

Comment: I like how you say 600 hearts of damage only kills most of the time. Tell me, what can tank that?!

Comment: @JLaBella When you are in creative mode, nothing except falling into the void can kill you :) (`/kill` deals "void damage"). If you think this answer is a good one, you can upvote it :)

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/effect give <player> instant_damage 30 200`, `/effect give <Player> resistance 1000000 0`, `/effect clear <player> resistance`

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to kill some one is to teleport them over lava

Comment: I like it. Using just vanilla console commands, a simple way to kill someone. What if you want to keep their stuff? Teleport them somewhere really high?

Answer (score 0):

You have to be in the game to kill anyone without any plugins.

You can install the Butcher plugin which allows you to kill mobs and other players from the console.

Answer (score -1):

As of Minecraft 1.8, the `/kill` command kills a specified entity instead of just the player who used it, meaning that `/kill <playername>` just works.